# get user Principale Name

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, gwt, active-directory

we have a Java Web Application ( GWT) and we need to authenticate our users with Active Directory Authentication.
Our goal is only  to get the user principal Name. I have found many suggest ( from Google research), but I'm little bit confused,so
- What are the steps required to configure Tomcat to obtain such information about AD users ?
- What should I change in the web.xml file of the web application?

All I need is to have a small example for both the questions

Thanks

Comment: One way is to configure the LDAP settings.

Comment: Where do I configure LDAP settings ? In Tomcat file configuration like  server.xml and web.xml ? Thanks

Comment: It seems that Waffle Library meets our needs. http://dblock.github.io/waffle/